# Remove 2nd axis from chart

Tags: excel, charts, axes

[image]

Hi,

Please see my chart above, I have the 2nd axis (01,02,03) which is required to maintain the order in which the data is presented however, my preference is for the 2nd axis not be visible in the chart.Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I presume your data comes from a pivot?
If so, you could simply sort your row fields from Z->A .

Hope it helps,

Wouter